# Mongo-go-driver: context deadline exceeded

Tags: mongodb, go

I have recently upgraded to the newer and offical golang mongo driver for an app I am working on.
All is work prefectly for my local development however when I hook it up and point to my backend server I am getting a 'context deadline exceeded' when calling the client.Ping(...) method.

The old driver code still works fine and I also print out the connection string and can copy and paste this into the compass app and it works without issues.

However for the life of me I cant work out why this new code is return a context timeout. Only different thing is that mongo is running on a non-standard port of 32680 and I am also using the mgm package. However it just using the offical mongo driver under the hood.

Mongo version is: 4.0.12 (locally and remote)

Connection code is here:

```
// NewClient creates a mongo DateBase connection
func NewClient(cfg config.Mongo) (*Client, error) {
    // create database connection string
    conStr := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s", cfg.Username, cfg.Password, cfg.Host, cfg.Port)

    // set mgm conf ie ctxTimeout value
    conf := mgm.Config{CtxTimeout: cfg.CtxTimeout}

    // setup mgm / DateBase connection
    err := mgm.SetDefaultConfig(&conf, cfg.Database, options.Client().ApplyURI(conStr))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "failed to connect to mongodb. cfg: %+v. conStr: %+v.", cfg, conStr)
    }

    // get access to underlying mongodb client driver, db and mgmConfig. Need for adding additional tools like seeding/migrations/etc
    mgmCfg, client, db, err := mgm.DefaultConfigs()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to return mgm.DefaultConfigs")
    }

    // NOTE: fails here!
    if err := client.Ping(mgm.Ctx(), readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "Ping failed to mongodb. cfg: %+v. conStr: %+v. mgmCfg: %+v", cfg, conStr, mgmCfg)
    }

    return &Client{
        cfg:    cfg,
        mgmCfg: mgmCfg,
        client: client,
        db:     db,
    }, nil
}
```

HELP! I have no idea how I can debug this anymore that I have?

Comment: What is the value of `cfg.CtxTimeout`? If that is `0` or very small, the timeout error may be justified.

Comment: Add the contents of ctx to the question, redacting the password.

Comment: Here is an output from a unit test when run againest the backend box: ```=== RUN   TestAllDisks
    mongodb.go:74: db connection failed:  Ping failed to mongodb. cfg: {Username:root Password:Password! Database:test Host:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Port:32680 CtxTimeout:10s}. conStr: mongodb://root:Password!@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:32680. mgmCfg: &{CtxTimeout:10s}: context deadline exceeded
--- FAIL: TestAllDisks (10.00s)
```

Comment: Same issue. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your authsource in your DSN,

something like

```
mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DBNAME?authsource=AUTHSOURCE
```

Comment: Yeah I added this and again it works locally, but not with my remote...